# Simple script with an error, variable is not defined

Tags: python

im trying to write a very basic sleep interval script and a starter script 
but for some reason that I can't understand I get an error message

CODE:

```
def intervals():
    while True:
        try:
            interval = input('[?] Intervals in seconds [default = 0s]:\t') or 0
            interval = int(interval)
            print(f'[+] Sleep for: {interval} seconds after each message Sent')
            return interval
        except:
            print(f'[!] Error: {interval} Not a number')


def intervals_start(interval):
    sleep(interval)

intervals()
intervals_start(interval)
```

ERROR:

```
[?] Intervals in seconds [default = 0s]:    5
[+] Sleep for: 5 seconds after each message Sent
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***********/testing.py", line 49, in <module>
    intervals_start(interval)
NameError: name 'interval' is not defined
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: On your last line, where exactly do you expect to get your `interval` parameter from?

Comment: Where do you think you defined `interval` prior to the statement `intervals_start(interval)`?  And do you know the difference between global and local variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a variable `interval` into a function `intervals_start()`, but nowhere in the code did you assign `interval` a value.

You need to capture the result of `intervals()`

`interval = intervals()`

then you can safely pass the user selected `interval` into `intervals_start()`

Comment: Thanks!! this really help me a lot, new codding sry if its a newbie question... 